# Symfony 1.4 preUpdate method never firing

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I've got the following model class:

```
class ContractDetails extends BaseContractDetails {

    public function updateContractDetailsByConId($conId, $key, $value) {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
              ->update('ContractDetails');
        if ($value === null) {
            $q->set($key, 'NULL');
        } else {
            $q->set($key, '?', $value);
        }

        $q->where('cd_con_id = ?', $conId)
                ->execute();

        return $q;
    }
    public function preUpdate($values) {
        $test = "test";
    }
 }
```

What I want is to run some code before the "updateContractDetailsByConId" method row is updated. From my investigations I should be able to use the built in hooks i.e. preUpdate 
But the preUpdate method is never running.

Any ideas why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook to the DQL Callbacks when you update from a DQL query. See [documentation here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/event-listeners.html#dql-hooks) for more info.

in your code, you need to update the `preUpdate` for

```
public function preDqlUpdate($values) {
   $test = "test";
}
```

Don't forget, as mentioned in the documentation that you need to implicitly turn the DQL callbacks on. In your ProjectConfiguration.class.php file, add:

```
public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager)
{
   $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_USE_DQL_CALLBACKS, true);
}
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks very much. I take it then that if im updating directly via the model's object I would use preUpdate?

Comment: @Trevelyan005 Exactly. You can create a `updateHook` function and call it from both if they do the same thing.